# Find the value of k such that the following function is differentiable at x=0

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, continuity

$$h(x)=\begin{cases}
{4x+2x^2 \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{} & \text{if $x <0$} \\[6pt]
{x}\cdot{\cos(x)}+ kx &  \text{if $x\geq0$} \\
\end{cases}
$$

I know how to prove they are continuous but how do I show the function is differentiable? Any ideas please? I think $k=3$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be such a function, you may try to expand the details about
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{-}}\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}
\end{align*}
and solve for $k$.

Comment: Can't I differentiate both sides and put x=0 to find k?

Comment: I guess you mean $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}f'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}f'(x)$, in this case, it works, but it needs some reasoning, but the safest way to do this question is the left-right limit of the difference quotient.

Comment: You can differentiate the expression on the right and plug in $0$, but that won't work for the expression on the left, which is not defined at $0$.  And taking the limit of $f'(x)$ as $x \to 0^+$ has no guarantee of being correct.  (Contrary to what @user284331 says, in this case it does NOT work.  (I expect that user284331 just didn't check carefully; this shouldn't be controversial.))

Comment: (If you use, say, $4x$ instead of $4x + 2x^2 \sin(1/x)$ on the left, then it's OK to differentiate and plug in $0$, because even though that formula is only given to apply when $x < 0$, the fact that it has a derivative if extended to (and even beyond) $0$ means that the derivative that you get this way is the desired left-hand limit.  But $4x + 2x^2 \sin(1/x)$ doesn't give you any result at $x = 0$.)

Comment: @TobyBartels, I am sorry that I didn't check carefully, yes, the left side would cause some problem. So that's why I said the safest way is to deal with the both-sided difference quotient.

Comment: And one point for extra information, if the function is twice differentiable at the zero, then it goes through (because then $f'$ has to be continuous at the zero).

Comment: Right, but I'm not sure how much twice-differentiability gets you that you wouldn't already have known.  Suppose that $f(x)$ is defined to be $g(x)$ for $x < 0$, $h(x)$ for $x > 0$, and $L$ for $x = 0$.  For continuity, you must check that the appropriate one-sided limits for $g$ and $h$ are $L$, which the OP knows how to do.  Having done so, if $g'(0)$ and $h'(0)$ exist and are equal, then $f'(0)$ is equal to them, nothing more required.  Continuity of the first derivative (which you wabt to use second differentiability to guarantee) is not needed.  The reason is that …

Comment: … if $g'(0)$ exists at all, then (first) $g$ is continuous at $0$, so $g(0) = L$, so $g'(0)$ is the limit of $(g(x) - g(0))/(x - 0) = (g(x) - L)/x$, and so in particular the left-handed limit of this exists and equals $g'(0)$.  And similarly, the right-handed limit of $(h(x) - L)/x$ exists and equals $h'(0)$.  And since these are the same, and since $f(x)$ is either $g(x)$ or $h(x)$ as $x \to 0$ (depending on the side), this means that the two-sided limit of $(f(x) - f(0))/(x - 0) = (f(x) - L)/x$ exists and equals these.  And this last limit is $f'(0)$.  No continuity of $g'$ or $h'$ needed.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to say, using twice differentiable is simply no hope in this question, I said that simply because for knowledge, not the strategy to tackle this question, sorry for once again the "misleading" .

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Delta (x)=\frac{f (x)-f (0)}{x-0} $

with $f (0)=0.$

$$\lim_{0^-}\Delta (x)=\lim_{0^-}(4+2x\sin (1/x))=4$$
since
$$|x\sin (1/x)|\le |x|$$

on the right,

$$\lim_{0^+}\Delta (x)=\lim_{0^+}(\cos (x)+k)=1+k $$

$f $ is differentiable at $0$ if $$1+k=4. $$